# Форматный вывод: вывести строку с заранее неизвестным количеством заполнителей

Tags: python, форматирование

Как используя форматный вывод вывести строку с заранее неизвестным количеством заполнителей? `print('{n: <len}')` требует литерал на место len

Вывожу таблицу. Надо как-то отрегулировать ширину колонок. Нет ли в питоне какой библиотеки, которая поддерживает форматный вывод с заранее неизвестным количеством знаков, чтобы работал какой-то такой код?

```
def print_table():
   max_len = 0
   for header in table['header']:
     max_len = max(len(header), max_len)
   for row in table['value']:
     for value in row:
       max_len = max(max_len, len(value))

   for header in table['header']:
     print('{header: <max_len}'.format(header = header, max_len = max_len), end = '')
   print('')
   for row in table['value']:
     for value in row:
       max_len = max(max_len, len(value))
```

Comment: думаю, вам стоит ознакомиться с [этим](https://www.educba.com/python-print-table/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто возьмите `max_len` еще раз в фигурные скобки, тогда сначала подставится он, потом подставится `header` в соответствии с подставленным `max_len`:

```
print('{header: <{max_len}}'.format(header=header, max_len=max_len), end = '')
```

Демонстрация:

```
header = "заголовок"
max_len = 30
print(f'{header:*<{max_len}}')
max_len = 31
print(f'{header:*<{max_len}}')
```

Выведет:

```
заголовок*********************
заголовок**********************
```